How many times has a NBA MVP faced off against a NBA Defensive Player of the Year in the playoffs?
With potential MVP Nikola Jokic facing off against potential Defensive Player of the Year Rudy Gobert, I was wondering how many times has a matchup like this in the playoffs occurred and which award winner/award winner’s team has won these matchups the most?

Won't a question like this and it's answers be outdated someday?
